# Cannot upload file to google drive from laravel using guzzle

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I am trying to upload files to google drive (v3 api), but the request returns unsupported content error. The same request works fine in postman

```
$client = new Client();
    
$headers = [
    'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$token,
   ];
$upload = $client->request('POST', 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart', [
                 'multipart' => [
                     [
                        'name'     => 'metadata',
                        'contents' => json_encode($data)
                     ],
                     [
                        'name'     => 'media',
                        'contents' => file_get_contents($file)
                     ]
                 ],
                   'headers' => $headers,
           ]);
```

#### Success Postman request

[image: postman sample]

#### Request Headers

[image: request headers]

#### data.json

```
{
  "name": "data.json",
  "parents": [
      "<id here>"
  ]
}
```

Comment: show the screenshot of your success 200 postman request with the headers(you can black out sensitive data)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHLUD.png

Comment: @bhucho here the header image https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Jk2P.png

Comment: are you sure you want to send json_encode data here `json_encode($data)` as your postman shows that you have uploaded both as json files

Comment: yes i have to send json enoded data, because the $data contains the key name and parent id. name will change for all the file to be uploaded

Comment: @Dhamo Any updates to this question? Have you tried something else to solve the issue? Please, share with us any efforts and feel free to ask again if the problem is still unresolved.

Comment: @Tinxuanna the issue is solved. I used filesystem to resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

```
$client = new Client();
$headers = [
    'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$token,
];
$storeToDrive = $client->post('https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart', [
    'multipart' => [
        [
            'name'     => '',
            'contents' => fopen('your meta file path', 'r'),
        ],
        [
            'name'     => '',
            'contents' => fopen('path of the file that you want to upload', 'r'),
        ]
    ],
    'headers' => $headers,
]);
```

As per documentation, the api supports only 2 parts in body of the request. The first one should be meta data and the second one is the file to be uploaded. In postman i added both the body items as separate file, but in code i used json_encode() and file_get_contents(). when we use json_encode() in upload, it shows unsupported meta or the file uploaded with the mime type "application/octet-stream".
fopen() is the only solution worked for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).